# Double action on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, segue

First, I'm a new iOS developer.

I has 2 UITableView.

- First UITableView use for Search.
- Second UITableView use for see information.

I'm create button for go to second UITableView

- press control+drag button to second UITableView.
- And set identifier is "gotoF10"

If click button. Connector will get @"special_selected_f10" to process at requestEWIServiceFinish method.

```
- (IBAction)btnf10
{
    NSMutableDictionary *content = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [content setValue:[[AppSetting sharedInstance] token] forKey:@"ewitoken"];
];
    [[EWIConnector connector] requestEWIService:@"special_selected_f10" requestData:content delegate:self];
}
```

If has @"special_selected_f10" from below code. It will follow Identifier name for go to second UITableView and response data.

```
- (void) requestEWIServiceStart:(EWIConnector *)connector{

    NSLog(@"start %@",connector.endpoint);
}

- (void) requestEWIServiceFinish:(EWIConnector *)connector responseData:(NSDictionary *)responseData{

    NSLog(@"finish %@",connector.serviceName);
    NSLog(@"response %@",responseData);

    if ([connector.serviceName isEqualToString:@"special_selected_f10"])
    {
        NSLog(@"finish %@", connector.serviceName);
        NSDictionary *content = responseData[@"content"];
        NSString *stAlertMes = [content objectForKey:@"alertMessage"];
        stAlertMes = [self getString:stAlertMes];
        NSLog(@"AlertMSG : %@", stAlertMes);
        if (![stAlertMes isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"ALERT MESSAGE : %@", stAlertMes);
            gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected = [[NSArray alloc] init];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"HAS DATA");
            gloablOnWherehouse.arTableDataSelected  = [content objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailF10Collection"];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoF10" sender:nil];

            //labelStatus.text = @"";
        }
    }
else
    {
        NSLog(@"response %@",responseData);
    }

}
```

This is a code from second UITableView for response data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell";
    DisplayEffectQtyViewCell *cell = [self.tableViewDetailList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DisplayEffectQtyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    } else {
        if (globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected) {
            NSMutableArray *myMutbleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [myMutbleArray addObject:globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected];

            if (myMutbleArray)
            {
                NSDictionary *myDic = [globlOnDisplayEffect.arTableDataSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                NSDictionary *cont = [myDic objectForKey:@"DataList_SPI_DetailF10"];
                NSString *f10_cmpt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_cmpt"]];
                NSString *f10_dt = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_dt"]];
                NSString *f10_item = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_item"]];
                NSString *f10_lot = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_lot"]];
                NSString *f10_model = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_model"]];
                NSString *f10_of = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_of"]];
                NSString *f10_semi = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_semi"]];
                NSString *f10_tm = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_tm"]];
                NSString *f10_uncmp = [self getString:[cont objectForKey:@"f10_uncmp"]];

                [cell setf10_cmpt:f10_cmpt setf10_dt:f10_dt setf10_item:f10_item setf10_lot:f10_lot setf10_model:f10_model setf10_of:f10_of setf10_semi:f10_semi setf10_tm:f10_tm setf10_uncmp:f10_uncmp];


            }
        }
    }

    return cell;

}
```

From upper is a concept of my application.

But, When i'm click button.
From debug IBAction isn't take @"special_selected_f10" to check on "requestEWIServiceFinish" method.
It's go to second UITableView and response empty data. Before back to first UITableView and follow from my concept again.

So, My application has 2 second UITableView when i'm click button.
(empty second UITableView and work second UITableView)

I can a little speak English.
Sorry for my bad English language.

Comment: What i understood.You have connected segue directly to tableview from button. Then you have attached an action to that button also.So when the button is clicked the action will not be called.Segue is performed.Thats why your NSLog and response data is not working.

Comment: How to resolve it?
I'm a new developer. So if you has idea to resolve it. Please help me.
I'm understood. I'm create direct action to next UITableView. So when i clicked button. It's must direct action to next UITableView before follow from segue identifier. Right?. If true. Can you tell me how to go next UITableView by identifier.

Comment: connect the segue from controller to the next tableview. Not from the button.

Comment: Can you explain me? or show example to me. please

Comment: Ok. first google how to create segue between two controllers. then create segue from your first view controller to the tableview controller where your are showing response data.Give name to segue.

Comment: You whole setup will remain the same. You have to delete "gotoF10" segue which you created from the button. Then create the new segue as i explained above.

Comment: Thank you brother. I will try...